# connect ROS With Serial port

Tags: serial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new with ROS
Can some one please tell how to send strings to PC USB port from  virtual machine
as serial communication  ..
I read cereal communication but not able to get it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134076/connect-ros-with-serial-port/) by [anantsarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/12541/anantsarin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

please see this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/84821/how-to-use-serial-port-in-ros/)

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mr.karimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/9676/mr.karimi/) on 2014-02-28**:
Ship Khat!  :D